# R package `bfast` error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, package

I am using the R package `bfast` to detect any change point in a time series, and come across the following error. Is there any suggestion? Thanks a lot.

```
library(bfast)
Mydata = Nile
bf1 <- bfast01(data = Mydata)
```

Error in if (is.nan(p0) || p0 < a2 || p0 > (1 - a2)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `bfast01` tries to guess the model from the other function arguments. I'm not too familiar with `bfast` but this seems to lead to the error on the `Nile` data.

If we explicitly specify the model,

```
fit <- bfast01(Nile, formula = response ~ trend);
```

there won't be an error, and `bfast01` picks up a change point at index 28.

```
fit$breakpoints;
#[1] 28
```

This result is consistent with results from a similar change point analysis using `changepoint`:

```
changepoint::cpt.mean(Nile, class = FALSE);
#    cpt conf.value
#     28          1
```

Note that for the `bfast` change point analysis, a model involving only a `trend` component seems sufficient, as the seasonal/autoregressive effects occur on a smaller scale. You'll need to check the validity of the model based on your real data.

Comment: No worries @YangYang; glad to help.